# Unzip file using mule esb

Tags: file, mule

My requirement is to unzip the files from .zip file.

I know that this can be done by calling the java class, is there any other alternative?

Comment: Mule doesn't have a zip transformer according to this:- [link](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/using-transformers#compression) But you can always write a zip/unzip transformer according to your need like:- [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.soitoolkit.commons.components/soitoolkit-commons-mule/0.6.0/org/soitoolkit/commons/mule/zip/UnzipTransformer.java/)

Answer (score 0):

There is Gzip Uncompress Transformer you can uncompress with this transformer

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/transformers-configuration-reference#gzip-uncompress-transformer